# Does ejabberd support offline file transfers?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I am working on an XMPP client, using ejabberd as server.
My question is how can I support offline file transferring?

I only want to do the offline file transferring for image files.

For example, 
I can transfer an image to John even if he is offline.
When John comes back online, 
the server will send him the image.

How can I do that?

Comment: Any solution to support offline file transferring ?

Comment: I use Openfire server and Conversation android client, I need step by step tutorial for implementing http server for offline file transfering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XMPP had an extension for this - [XEP-0129: WebDAV File Transfers](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0129.html) -  but it is deferred!

I am searching for the same solution. I came across it, but did not find a XMPP server still supporting it.

Still searching for a solution.

Answer (score 3):

There is currently no extension for XMPP to allow offline file transfers.

Presumably this would need to be supported by the recipient's server, and it would need to be implemented as a server-specific plugin.

Alternatively a project that may be of interest to you is **Jabber Disk**, which allows you to upload a file via XMPP, and then returns a HTTP URL you can send to people (for example as an offline message).

Comment: the link you have mentioned is dead. It is giving 404

Comment: Is it fine if I upload files with PHP on my server and use the url for file sending?

Comment: @JayeshJain Yes. You can use http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0066.html for sharing the URL

Answer (score 1):

We implemented offline file transfer is TextOne mobile client, but we had to do a custom module. There is no good specification for that yet.

However, for a simple need as you have, I think you could implement it purely client side (uploading to an HTTP server) and use XMPP for signaling.

Comment: Very Sad. We are in 2018 and file transfers unsupported

Comment: Well it is supported, but not inband. It works well "out-of-band", as it should. You do not want to transfer binary inside the XMPP stream. You do the signaling over XMPP and the actual file transfer using HTTPS or another protocol.