# How to fix offline file transfer in ejabberd?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I am working on a xmpp client, using eJabberd as server. My question is How can I support offline file transferring?

I only want to do the offline file transferring,For example, I can transfer an image to user named as Purushottam even he is offline. When Purushottam will come back Online, the server will send him the image.

How can I do that? Is there any module for this in ejabberd ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Ejabberd Support Offline File Transfer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981459/can-ejabberd-support-offline-file-transfer)

Answer (score 1):

**Answer to question 1:**
You can send it post it to your server using a HTML form upload or some REST service. After which you send a stanza to your user notifying that it needs to download the file from an accessable location on your server.

See also:
[file transfer in multi user chat to muliple users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20564826/file-transfer-in-multi-user-chat-to-muliple-users/20576743#20576743)

**Answer to question 2:**
As mentioned already: no